# Bash script, appending a file with a ascii banner

Tags: linux, bash

I want to put a ascii banner into the `/etc/motd` file but every time i try i always get the error,

```
test.sh: line 3: S: command not found
test.sh: line 3: S: command not found
test.sh: line 4: S: command not found
test.sh: line 4: S: command not found
test.sh: line 4: S: command not found
test.sh: line 4: S: command not found
```

Im trying to use the following script;

```
 #!/usr/bin/env bash

 sudo cat > /etc/motd << EOF

 sdSS_SSSSSSbs    sSSs    sSSs  sdSS_SSSSSSbs
 YSSS~S%SSSSSP   d%%SP   d%%SP  YSSS~S%SSSSSP
      S%S       d%S'    d%S'         S%S
      S%S       S%S     S%|          S%S
      S&S       S&S     S&S          S&S
      S&S       S&S_Ss  Y&Ss         S&S
      S&S       S&S~SP  `S&&S        S&S
      S&S       S&S       `S*S       S&S
      S*S       S*b        l*S       S*S
      S*S       S*S.      .S*P       S*S
      S*S        SSSbs  sSS*S        S*S
      S*S         YSSP  YSS'         S*S
      SP                             SP
      Y                              Y

 EOF
```

Is there a way to escape the whole block or am i going in the wrong direction

Comment: Quote `EOF` on `cat` line as `sudo cat > /etc/motd << 'EOF'`

Comment: @anubhava thank you .. that worked very nice